Inequality involving derivatives of Legendre polynomials
In proving stability of a damped Runge-Kutta-Legendre finite difference method I realize that the result would follow from an inequality involving the Legendre polynomials.
The question is simple. Prove that
$$
P_n^{\prime \prime}(x) \cdot P_n(x) \leq P_n^{\prime}(x)^2 \textrm{ for } x \geq 1,
$$
where $P_n(x)$ is the n:th Legendre polynomial with the normalization $P_n(1)=1$.
There are tons of relations among the Legendre polynomials, but for some reason I cannot find the right ones to prove this. If it is true at all.

The Legendre polynomial $P_n(x)$ has $n$ simple real roots in $(-1,1)$, then we can write
$$P_n(x)=a_n \prod_{i=1}^n (x-x_i)$$
$$\implies \ln(P_n(x)) = \log(a_n) + \sum_{i=1}^n\ln(x-x_i)$$
As the functions $\ln(x-x_i)$ are concave for all $x\ge 1$, $\ln(P_n(x))$ is also a concave function. Then
$$\left(\ln(P_n(x))\right)''\le0\iff \frac{P''_n(x)P_n(x)-(P_n'(x))^2}{(P_n(x)^2}\le 0\iff P''_n(x)P_n(x)\le(P_n'(x))^2$$
Q.E.D

Thanks, that was much simpler than I expected.
